# Dependency issues when using 'stack build --profile'?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ stack new profiling-test
$ cd profiling-test
$ stack build --profile
```

A new project is initialized with `lts-7.2` and a default template.  I get the error:

```
While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package base in known packages

--  Failure when adding dependencies:
      base: needed (>=4.7 && <5), stack configuration has no specified version (latest applicable is 4.9.0.0)
    needed for package profiling-test-0.1.0.0

Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in ~/profiling-test/stack.yaml
- base-4.9.0.0

You may also want to try the 'stack solver' command
```

If I just do `stack build`, it compiles fine without any errors.

I've added `base-4.9.0.0` to `extra-deps` in `stack.yaml`, but I get the same error.

My stack version is:

```
$ stack --version
Version 1.1.3, Git revision 225df244ea346a8dc880ef911b002583486a92b2 x86_64 hpack-0.14.0
```

And I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 trusty.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out after finding https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1331.

Solution:

- Instead of doing

  ```
  $ stack build --profile
  ```
- Do:

  ```
  $ stack build --profile --no-system-ghc
  ```

And just add `--no-system-ghc` to everything.  You might potentially need to do `stack setup --no-system-ghc` before everything too?

Alternatively, as suggested by the comments, you can add this to the `stack.yaml` for the project or for your global stack project.

Comment: if you want to add `--no-system-ghc` flag to all commands, you may as well add it to `stack.yaml` (possibly your local one, not the project's one)